# how to convert Doctrine object into json

Tags: php, json, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I am using Doctrine 1.2, how could I get the query object into json / array format?

```
$user = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('u.id, u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname')
->from('User u')
->orderby('u.id')
->execute();
```

Comment: Second response is very good.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706485/how-to-encode-doctrine-entities-to-json-in-symfony-2-0-ajax-application][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706485/how-to-encode-doctrine-entities-to-json-in-symfony-2-0-ajax-application

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A solution might be to use the [`toArray()`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/working-with-models:arrays-and-objects:to-array) method on the `$user` object, to have a simple array containing only the data youre interested in, and, then, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to convert that PHP array to a JSON string.

Something like this, I suppose :

```
$user = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('u.id, u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname')
->from('User u')
->orderby('u.id')
->execute();

$userArray = $user->toArray();
$json = json_encode($userArray);
```

*(Not tested, but it should not be too far from working...)*

Comment: does this handle relations?

Comment: Please, stop using ``json_encode`` ! Php have excellent serializing library, with Symfony + Doctrine, you can use ``Symfony\Component\Serializer``, play with annotations to include or not some relation.

Answer (score 8):

Trouble with *$record->exportTo('json')* is that it will export **all** record fields. And in most cases it's not a desirable behaviour (for e.g. when this piece of json should be passed to browser). One way to limit the scope of export is to specify fields in DQL select:

```
$user = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('u.id, u.name')
            ->from('User u')
            ->addWhere('u.id = ?', $id)
            ->fetchOne();

$user_json = $user->exportTo('json');
```

$user_json then will have something like this:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "John Smith",
    "password": null,
    "deleted": null
}
```

So it does not expose "password" field value but *does* expose underlying database structure. Again, might not be what we want.
What I do is specify fields in DQL select + fetch as array then json encode:

```
$user = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('u.id, u.name')
            ->from('User u')
            ->addWhere('u.id = ?', $id)
            ->fetchOne(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

$user_json = json_encode($user);
```

In this case json will look like something like:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "John Smith"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$users2 = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('u.id, u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname')
->from('User u')
->orderby('u.id');
$tmp2 = $users2->fetchArray();
```

I don't know why the **toArray**() will give the other field in the table, 
e.g. it will have the "password" field, 
it seems **fetchArray**() can give me the correct fields in query.

toArray()

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => user1
            [password] => password
            [firstname] => John
            [lastname] => Smith
        )
```

fetchArray()

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => user1
            [firstname] => John
            [lastname] => Smith
        )
```

Comment: toArray is a direct transformation of the object into an array format. fetchArray is a bit more clever in the sense that it's not really a transformation, but more of an extraction.

Answer (score 1):

For JSON :

```
$user->exportTo('json');
```

;-)

Answer (score -1):

Now [Doctrine ORM Transformations](https://github.com/Indaxia/doctrine-orm-transformations) is out, it allows to convert entities to scalar arrays and back

```
class User implements ITransformable {
    use Transformable;
// ...
echo json_encode($user->toArray());
```