# Symfony 2 Doctrine export to JSON

Tags: php, web-services, json, doctrine, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2 with Doctrine 2 to create a web service(JSON) for an iOS app.

To fetch my entity i do:

```
$articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UdoPaddujourBundle:MenuArticle')->findAll();
```

I must tell you that:

```
$article = array();
$article = $articles->toArray();
```

Gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object
```

Same thing happends with

```
$article = $articles->exportTo('json');
```

---

How can i create a json response ?

Kind Regards,
Cearnau Dan

Edit:
var_dump($articles) =

```
array(18) {
   [0]=>
     object(Udo\PaddujourBundle\Entity\MenuArticle)#50 (4) {
    ["id":"Udo\PaddujourBundle\Entity\MenuArticle":private]=>
    int(1)
    ["name":"Udo\PaddujourBundle\Entity\MenuArticle":private]=>
    string(17) "My Article Name 1"
    ["description":"Udo\PaddujourBundle\Entity\MenuArticle":private]=>
    string(26) "My Article Description 1"
    ["price":"Udo\PaddujourBundle\Entity\MenuArticle":private]=>
    float(20)
    }
   [1]=> ...
```

## - LATER EDIT

How can i loop through all the "property names" ? 
This is what i've got:

```
$myarray=array(); 
$myArray["name"]=array(); 
$myArray["description"]=array(); 
foreach($articles in $article) 
{ 
  array_push($myArray["name"], $article->getName());
  array_push($myArray["description"], $article->getDescription()); 
}
```

Comment: What gives you `var_dump($articles);` ?

Comment: array(18) {
  [0]=>
  object(Udo\PaddujourBundle\Entity\MenuArticle)#50 (4) {
    ["id":"Udo\PaddujourBundle\Entity\MenuArticle":private]=>
    int(1)
    ["name":"Udo\PaddujourBundle\Entity\MenuArticle":private]=>
    string(17) "My Article Name 1"
    ["description":"Udo\PaddujourBundle\Entity\MenuArticle":private]=>
    string(24) "My Article Description 1"
    ["price":"Udo\PaddujourBundle\Entity\MenuArticle":private]=>
    float(20)
  }
  [1]=>
  **And so on til [17]**

Comment: What gives you `json_encode($articles);` ?

Comment: `$articles` already is an array of `MenuArticle` objects.

Comment: json_encode($articles) gives: [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]. I think json_encode wants an array of strings not an array of objects.

Comment: I know this is really old, but for reference, $obj->toArray() only works in doctrine 1.x, so that's why we get that error in Symfony2 using doctrine 2.

Answer (score 14):

If you use a doctrine query you can also do this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT ma FROM UdoPaddujourBundle:MenuArticle ma ...etc');
$myArray = $query->getArrayResult();
```

and then use `json_encode($myArray);`

See [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats) for more details.

Comment: Thanks it works but it's pretty nasty compared to the "GetRepository()" metod.But if this is the only easy way to get a json response i have to deal with it.

Comment: You could move the method to a custom repository and then you won't have to look at it ;-)

Comment: Or take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706485/how-to-encode-doctrine-entities-to-json-in-symfony-2-0-ajax-application

Comment: You really want to work with your objects instead of using DQL queries. The interface is much easier to work with.

Answer (score 3):

If you're coming from a symfony 1.x background, there was a lot more "magic" available for entities, including helpers to convert to arrays and so forth.

In Symfony2, most of the magic is gone; entities in particular are now plain old PHP objects that happen to be managed by Doctrine 2 for persistence to the database, which means that to have methods such as `toArray()` available on your domain object, you must implement them yourself. It should be fairly trivial to do -- simply return a key-value array with `("name of property" => "value of property")`... if you have relationships set up with other entities, you'll need to implement a `toArray()` method on those as well, and simply call that from the main entity when you're converting.

Then, once you have your object array, `$json = json_encode($array);` will give you a JSON string to send as your response.

Comment: How can i loop through all the "property names" ? the best i code is this `$myarray=array(); $myArray["name"]=array(); $myArray["description"]=array(); foreach($articles in $article) { array_push($myArray["name"], $article->getName()); array_push($myArray["description"], $article->getDescription()); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode($articles)` when you entity (or any other object) implements `JsonSerializable`:

```
<?php

namespace My\AppBundle\Entity;

use JsonSerializable;

class Channel implements JsonSerializable
{

    /*
     * All your fields, getters and setters.
     */

    /**
     * Returns serializable items.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->getName(),
            'description' => $this->getDescription(),
        ];
    }
}
```