# How can I send JSON response in symfony2 controller

Tags: php, javascript, json, symfony

I am using `jQuery` to edit my form which is built in `Symfony`.

I am showing the form in `jQuery` dialog and then submitting it.

Data is entering correctly in database.

But I don't know whether I need to send some `JSON` back to `jQuery`. Actually I am bit confused with `JSON` thing.

Suppose I have added a row in my table with ``jQuery and when I submit the form then after data is submitted I want to send back those row data so that I can dynamically add the table row to show the data added.

I am confused how can get that data back.

This is my current code:

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(new StepsType(), $entity);

$request = $this->getRequest();

$editForm->bindRequest($request);

if ($editForm->isValid()) {
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->render('::success.html.twig');               
}
```

This is just the template with success message.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

**Symfony 2.1**

```
$response = new Response(json_encode(array('name' => $name)));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return $response;
```

---

**Symfony 2.2** and higher

You have special [JsonResponse](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php) class, which serialises array to JSON:

```
return new JsonResponse(array('name' => $name));
```

---

But if your problem is **How to serialize entity** then you should have a look at [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst)

Assuming that you have it installed, you'll have simply to do

```
$serializedEntity = $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($entity, 'json');

return new Response($serializedEntity);
```

You should also check for similar problems on StackOverflow:

- [How to encode Doctrine entities to JSON in Symfony 2.0 AJAX application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706485/how-to-encode-doctrine-entities-to-json-in-symfony-2-0-ajax-application)
- [Symfony 2 Doctrine export to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013257/symfony-2-doctrine-export-to-json)

Comment: So how do we Serialize entity AND send it as a JSON Response? I've been searching for that for a week.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798532/symfony2-json-response-returns-weird-utf-characters

Comment: You can also use symfony JsonResponse (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse)

Comment: It's better to set content-type header return new Response($serializedEntity, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));

Comment: Sergii's suggestion is the best (at least for me), if I don't set the Content-Type, on the client I will receive a text/html content-type. If I use JsonResponse, for some weird reason I get a single string with the content inside

Answer (score 56):

Symfony 2.1 has a [JsonResponse](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php) class.

```
return new JsonResponse(array('name' => $name));
```

The passed in array will be JSON encoded the status code will default to 200 and the content type will be set to application/json.

There is also a handy `setCallback` function for JSONP.

Answer (score 19):

Since Symfony 3.1 you can use JSON Helper
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#json-helper

```
public function indexAction()
{
// returns '{"username":"jane.doe"}' and sets the proper Content-Type header
return $this->json(array('username' => 'jane.doe'));

// the shortcut defines three optional arguments
// return $this->json($data, $status = 200, $headers = array(), $context = array());
}
```

Answer (score 11):

To complete @thecatontheflat answer I would recommend to also wrap your action inside of a `try … catch` block. This will prevent your JSON endpoint from breaking on exceptions. Here's the skeleton I use:

```
public function someAction()
{
    try {

        // Your logic here...

        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => true,
            'data'    => [] // Your data here
        ]);

    } catch (\Exception $exception) {

        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => false,
            'code'    => $exception->getCode(),
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        ]);

    }
}
```

This way your endpoint will behave consistently even in case of errors and you will be able to treat them right on a client side.

Answer (score 9):

If your data is already serialized:

a) send a JSON response

```
public function someAction()
{
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents('path/to/file'));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

b) send a JSONP response (with callback)

```
public function someAction()
{
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent('/**/FUNCTION_CALLBACK_NAME(' . file_get_contents('path/to/file') . ');');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
    return $response;
}
```

If your data needs be serialized:

c) send a JSON response

```
public function someAction()
{
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData([some array]);
    return $response;
}
```

d) send a JSONP response (with callback)

```
public function someAction()
{
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData([some array]);
    $response->setCallback('FUNCTION_CALLBACK_NAME');
    return $response;
}
```

e) use groups in Symfony 3.x.x

**Create groups inside your Entities**

```
<?php

namespace Mindlahus;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * Some Super Class Name
 *
 * @ORM    able("table_name")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SomeSuperClassNameRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *  fields={"foo", "boo"},
 *  ignoreNull=false
 * )
 */
class SomeSuperClassName
{
    /**
     * @Groups({"group1", "group2"})
     */
    public $foo;
    /**
     * @Groups({"group1"})
     */
    public $date;

    /**
     * @Groups({"group3"})
     */
    public function getBar() // is* methods are also supported
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Normalize your Doctrine Object inside the logic of your application**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory;
// For annotations
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Loader\AnnotationLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;

...

$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Mindlahus:SomeSuperClassName');
$SomeSuperObject = $repository->findOneById($id);

$classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
$encoder = new JsonEncoder();
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);
$callback = function ($dateTime) {
    return $dateTime instanceof \DateTime
        ? $dateTime->format('m-d-Y')
        : '';
};
$normalizer->setCallbacks(array('date' => $callback));
$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
$data = $serializer->normalize($SomeSuperObject, null, array('groups' => array('group1')));

$response = new Response();
$response->setContent($serializer->serialize($data, 'json'));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using symfony 5 propably it will works.

```
$data = $serializer->serialize(array('key' => 'value'), JsonEncoder::FORMAT);

return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_OK, [], true);
```