# How do I return a twig rendered template as part of a JSON response?

Tags: php, json, symfony, twig

I want to return an HTML snippet as well as other values in a json string, here is what I have:

```
$html = $this->render('sometemplate.html.twig', array( 'somevar' => $somevar ) );
$response = new Response(json_encode( array("html" => $html, "name" => "Joe Bloggs") ));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

But all I get is `{"html":{"headers":{}}}`. Is there a way to just grab the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use `$this->renderView()` instead.

`$this->render()` returns a `Response` object, while `$this->renderView()` returns a string resulting from rendering a template.

Comment: Just adding that these methods are part of Symfony. The Twig core library uses $twig->display for outputting content, while $twig->render returns the content. Could be a bit confusing! :-)

Comment: another way could be the use of getContent() method of the Response object.