# Twig rendering into JSON object

Tags: ajax, json, symfony, twig

I have a twig template that I want to render, store in JSON object, and return as a response to a post request.

```
$response = json_decode('{"version":1,"status":"success"}', true);
$html = $this->render('DumoBundle:Test:Overlay.html.twig', 
     array('left'=>3,'right'=>4));
$response['html'] = $html;
$response= new Response(json_encode($response));
return $response
```

However, when I print the JSON object to console on the browser side, I see that is is the following:

```
{"version":1,"status":"success","html":{"headers":{}}}
```

How can I store all the HTML in the `html` property of my JSON obejct?

Comment: I found an ansewr: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257156/how-do-i-return-a-twig-rendered-template-as-part-of-a-json-response. I don't want to delete though because this this will give anyone else looking for this solution double chances of finding it.

Comment: Just for reference you also don't need to use `json_encode` as a response. Symfony has a specific `JSONResponse` class (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse) that will handle that stuff for you (headers, json_encode, etc).