# getJson / parseJson

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

This question is related to [Symfony2 JSON response returns weird UTF characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798532/symfony2-json-response-returns-weird-utf-characters) . I am trying to do an Ajax request to JSON data with GETJSON, using Symfony2 as a backend.

Should I be using parsejson or getjson is enough?

Comment: Have you tried it? `getJSON` will parse the response automatically.

Comment: The JSON returning from your original question is not valid. Close quesiton.