# How to attach cookies to JSON Response in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I have JSON endpoint which is used to add product to cart. It checks whether the cart already exists or no. If not then it creates a cart and the cart Id is stored in cookie. So I how do I  attach cookie to the symfony2's JsonResponse ?

In a non ajax version if I am rendering a template from my action I can use:

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie(‘cookie_name’, ‘cookie_value’));

$this->render('<template_path>', '<array_options>', $response);
```

Please help me on how to do it for a JsonResponse.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, you will find the answer under the following links:

[How can i send json response in symfony2 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714941/how-can-i-send-json-response-in-symfony2-controller)

http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html

The best way, to see links and learn, but if you will not find the answer, maybe this will be good:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie(‘cookie_name’, ‘cookie_value’));

return $response;
```

There is also a helpful JsonResponse class, which can make this even easier:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie(‘cookie_name’, ‘cookie_value’));

return $response;
```

I hope, this will be helpfull :)