# fullcalendar loaded with ajax symfony2 doctrine2

Tags: ajax, symfony, fullcalendar

this my function in controller

```
public function loadcalendarAction() {

    $eventsloaded = $this->container->get('calendarbundle.serviceloadcalendar')->loadCalendar();
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    //dump($eventsloaded);
    //die();
    $response->setData(array('events' => $eventsloaded));
    return $response;
}
```

the $eventsloaded is an array of 2 events in my database its OK .. but $response is empty i don't know why ..

[image: the response is empty]

and this my calendar_setting.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
    lang: 'ar-tn',
    buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
    weekNumbers: true,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    dayClick: function () {
        alert('a day has been clicked!');
    },
    events: Routing.generate('loadcalendar')
});
});
```

if the response not empty all the events will be displayed in the events:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this questions' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714941/how-can-i-send-json-response-in-symfony2-controller). You need either to use some external bundle (such as JMSSerializerBundle) to serialize entity, to pass it to json response, or implement something like `toArray()` method in your entity which will return an array of needed data from entity, after that you could do smth like:

```
$responseData = [];
foreach ($eventsloaded as $i => $event) {
    $responseData[$i] = $event->toArray();
}

return new JsonResponse($responseData);
```

Comment: thank you so much it works .. but it returns to me like this [{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;event 1&quot;,&quot;start_time&quot;:&quot;2016-01-28T09:00:00+0100&quot;,&quot;end_time&quot;:&quot;2016-01-31T09:00:00+0100&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:2,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;event 2&quot;,&quot;start_time&quot;:&quot;2016-01-25T12:00:00+0100&quot;,&quot;end_time&quot;:&quot;2016-01-25T16:00:00+0100&quot;}]   [{"id":1,"title":"event 1","start_time":"2016-01-28T09:00:00+0100","end_time":"2016-01-31T09:00:00+0100"},{"id":2,"title":"event 2","start_time":"2016-01-25T12:00:00+0100"}]

Comment: the answer is the filter raw in twig {{ events|raw }}