# Symfony: get parameter from request query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I can't implement search functionality with Symfony. This is what I have:

```
/**
 * CoffeeShop controller.
 *
 * @Route("/coffeeshops")
 */
class CoffeeShopController extends Controller
{

/**
 * @Route("/q?", name="api_coffeeshops_search")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function searchAction(Request $request){

    $chain = $request->query->get('chain');

    $result = new JsonResponse();
    $coffeeShops = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('CoreBundle:CoffeeShop')->findBy(array('chain' => $chain));

    $result->setContent($coffeeShops);
    return $result;
}
}
```

And when I submit query

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/coffeeshops/q?chain=2
```

I only get `null` as a response

Comment: You make sure that the "chain" 2 exists in database? However the char `?` in you route path definition there is unnecessary.

Comment: First step would be to be sure that there is a `chain : 2` entry in your database. Is it an id ? Or a number ?

Comment: Yes, there is chain with id 2

Comment: Hi, if you confirm that $coffeeShops has elements.. and $chain set correctly.. check jsonResponse, symfony version?? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11715894/2209876

Comment: Some thoughts: 1. remove the `?` in your route definition. 2. You try to select the entry by id? Then your findBy is wrong: `$coffeeShops = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('CoreBundle:CoffeeShop')->findBy(array('id' => $chain));` 3. Just a reminder `query->get` should be sanitized for security reasons or user `query->filter` 4. Is chain an related entity to your CoffeeShop entity? Then you should first select the chain by id and pass that result to your CoffeeShop query.