# Converting twig array to javascript to access objects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twig

I am trying to access object filed values that are passed from twig to javascript.

```
 <a href data-user_data="{{ users|json_encode }}">
```

With:

```
var userData = $(this).data('user_data');

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(userData);
```

returning

```
{}
```

Tried:

```
var myJSON = JSON.parse(subscriptionData);
```

Got:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Non of the posts from the site did not help..

Comment: What does `users` or `users|json_encode` look like?

Comment: users returns object but users|json_encode is empty. Can not figure out why is that? @mtsknn

Comment: Because it is an object with only private properties? (just a guess)

Comment: Yes. That is the problem. how could i solve it? @β.εηοιτ.βε

Comment: Either implement a [`toArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387162/symfony-2-php-json-encode) or add public getters.

Comment: Or implement [jsonserializable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php)

Comment: Ah, I knew there was something like that, but couldn't find it back, thx @DarkBee