# Doctrine get all fields of record

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

By default Symfony 2.5 uses Doctrine and for each table it has a class with private properties that connected with table fields and get and set methods for each field. But I want to get all fields from one record without using get method for each field in loop. Because  after that I have to send a JSON-object to front-end part. How can I do it? Because I don't want use get for each field, to get it value, I need values of all fields.

Comment: What you want is serializing your `Entity` into JSON. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706485/how-to-encode-doctrine-entities-to-json-in-symfony-2-0-ajax-application.

Comment: I think this library doesn't support.

Comment: Are there any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize Doctrine entities with the [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst). It's exactly designed for this type of problem. It can serialize your entity based on the getters it finds in the entity class.

Comment: I made these steps
composer require jms/serializer 0.13
$serializer = JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$serializer->serialize($object, 'json');
But Symfony returns me an error.

Comment: Attempted to load class "SerializerBuilder" from namespace "Acme\MyBundle\Controller\JMS\Serializer"

Comment: I see you've accapted the answer, thanks! So I hope you were successful in the end?

Comment: Yes) But the last question. This class makes value true for tinyINT fields from DB, how solve it?

Comment: I need their real values. But system returns me true.

Comment: It looks like your type on these fields is boolean. However, if you're getting an unexpected result from the serializer, you should possibly discuss this in a new SO question (don't forget to post the relevant part of your schema/annotations).