# Persist Doctrine ArrayCollection with only strings to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm persisting a field of type ArrayCollection to a MySQL database which contains only stings. The database field is of type "array" in the ORM definition and of type TEXT in the database.

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="currencies", type="array")
 */
private $currencies;
```

When persisted it looks like this in the database:

```
O:43:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":1:{s:54:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection_elements";a:3:{i:0;s:3:"EUR";i:1;s:3:"USD";i:2;s:3:"GBP";}}
```

Is there a way to get something more close to a json array into the database? Something like this:

```
['EUR', 'USD', 'GBP']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you setting an ArrayCollection to your $currencies property ?
Why don't you use an array ?

You may also use the "json_array" Doctrine type instead of "array".

Comment: Why would you ever use a ArrayCollection instead of an array? Because it's easier to handle. json_array as a type works.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine uses the PHP function `serialize()` when inserting into the database.

Upon fetching, it uses `deserialize()`.

You can simply use: `echo json_encode($entity->getCurrencies());`.

See also this question: [How to encode Doctrine entities to JSON in Symfony 2.0 AJAX application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706485/how-to-encode-doctrine-entities-to-json-in-symfony-2-0-ajax-application)

Comment: I want to have it saved in the database in a more cleaner way, the output is no problem.