# php array to json via json_encode creates empty array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array from a database in Symfony Doctrine that looks like this (using dd()):

```
array:2 [
  0 => App\Entity\Bg {#518
    -id: 2
    -name: "company"
    -partner: "Bill"
    -mail: "mail"
    -status: "awaiting"
    -last_changed: "25.03.2020"
  }
  1 => App\Entity\Bg {#520
    -id: 3
    -name: "company 2"
    -partner: "Max"
    -mail: "mail"
    -status: "awaiting"
    -last_changed: "25.03.2020"
  }
]
```

after using

```
json_encode($bgs);
```

the result is only

```
"[{},{}]"
```

What exactly is going on behind the scenes? Obviously I want json_encode to transform my array into a json_array, so I can send it in a response.

Comment: They look like objects of type `App\Entity\Bg` which may not have public properties.

Comment: have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706485/how-to-encode-doctrine-entities-to-json-in-symfony-2-0-ajax-application

Comment: If you're using PHP 7.4, you can utilize [custom object serialization](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.standard.magic-serialize). If you're using earlier versions, you could implement the [serializable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable) interface on your entity. Note that this has been deprecated as of 7.4.